# Expo push Notifications not working with stack navigation but does work in single App()

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to implement push notifications in my React Native app using ExpoPushNotifications and firebase FCM

I have been able to get a very simple app working with push notifications when all the configurations of the push notifications is done inside the app() component. I have managed to build the app and install on android device and have push notifications sent through FCM recieved by the app.

As soon as I add in further complexity to the App i.e. add in different navigation Stacks (one for authentication: signin, signup & one for authenticated: welcome screen etc etc). The Expo Notifications stop being recieved. There are no errors such as incorrect token etc and as far as i can tell the FCM and Expo are both "sending" the push notification its just not being registered by the app.

I have tried moving the Notification set up from App() into the other Stacks but still no luck.

I have tried googling this for a week now but all expo push notification examples just include App() as a single page app with no complexity and all issues related to failure in notifications people point to FCM and the set up, which i have already proved my setup with the FCM and creds etc works fine as the "basic" app works.

Has anyone set up a multi-navigation-stack app with numerous different screens and also have push notifications working with Expo Notificiations?

Answer (score 1):

- First, you create a context for your notifications

  ```
  import { createContext } from 'react';

  const NotificationContext = createContext();

  export default NotificationContext;
  ```
- Then, wrap your app with the context provider and pass the necessary functions and state

  ```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
  import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
  import { registerForPushNotificationsAsync } from './registerForPushNotifications';
  import { NotificationContext } from './NotificationContext';
  import SignInScreen from './screens/SignInScreen';
  import SignUpScreen from './screens/SignUpScreen';
  import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  export default function App() {
   const [notification, setNotification] = useState(null);
   const [expoPushToken, setExpoPushToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => {
      setExpoPushToken(token);
    });
  }, []);

   return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider value={{ notification, setNotification }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
   );
  }
  ```
- Once you completed above process and completed screen setup then you can access the notification state and functions using the useContext hook.

  ```
  import React from 'react';
  import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
  import { NotificationContext } from '../NotificationContext';

  function WelcomeScreen() {
   const { notification, setNotification } = React.useContext(NotificationContext);

   return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome to the app!</Text>
      {notification && <Text>Notification: {notification.data.body}</Text>}
      <Button title="Clear Notification" onPress={() => setNotification(null)} />
    </View>
   );
  }

  export default WelcomeScreen;
  ```

This way, you can manage the notifications state and functions from any component in your app